# Change default dark background in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to change default black background to #111. Here is the code that i tried to use

```
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">

        ...

        <Color x:Key="SystemAltHighColor">#111</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemAltHighColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemAltHighColor}"/>
        ...

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

But it doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not html, put the whole code. ie #111111, or if you want to add alpha, #FF111111

Comment: @ChrisW. Didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SystemAltHighColorBrush` is not a used brush in Windows 10 UWP. You can double check all used resources at the following path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>    Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml

If you mean the application's page background, you're looking for `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` as this is the default style used on each new page.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

You're trying to change theme resources (they differ between dark and light), so your change should reflect this. Override the theme dictionaries with the appropriate keys. As #111111 is very close to black, I took a fancy green for demo purposes.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <Color x:Key="SystemAltHighColor">#11CC11</Color>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <Color x:Key="SystemAltHighColor">#11CC11</Color>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```